# Should we add tag tips for the [text-processing] tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-tips

There were several grumpy users in chat talking about how boring or outright bad questions are the [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) tagged questions. One of the most pushed ideas was that text processing questions should include an attempt to get the desired output, the input, and the output (I think I got it right). Should we give a more detailed guidance to people asking these questions? If "yes", what would be a good, and [specific](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242355/213575) guidance text?

Answer (score 5):

I checked the 5 most recent [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) questions:

- [Extract multiple lines from text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164437/extract-multiple-lines-from-text-file)
- [How to update three CSV files based on a fourth file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164359/how-to-update-files-based-on-another-file)
- [Extract and format data with `cut` and `awk`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164346/extract-and-format-data-with-cut-and-awk)
- [Insert missing string in multiple ordered columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164207/insert-missing-string-in-multiple-ordered-columns)
- [Convert XML to SQL INSERT statements using the command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164136/convert-xml-to-sql-insert-statements-using-the-command-line)

Of those, only "Insert missing string in multiple ordered columns" was *asked* with [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing). So its OP is the only one who would have seen the tag tip. Its OP is also the one who most clearly doesn't need it, having given a properly formatting question with example input and output and even links to three other questions already reviewed.

So, I think it'd not really help...

Comment: Nice analysis, vis. most `text-processing` questions are probably not tagged by the OP.  However, having what Braiam suggests would still provide something to point subsequently ("Please read this...").  The tagger could even do both ;)

Comment: @goldilocks if we want something to point to, that'd be a good use of the tag wiki. Much nicer since we can edit it w/o asking the developers, and you can actually link to tag wikis.

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit my culpability in retagging at least three of the questions that [derobert mentions](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3235/6761) with the [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) tag.

My view is twofold: one, each of the questions I retagged was fundamentally about processing text and, two, consistent tagging allows people to follow tags, or in the case of the disgruntled chat people, ignore them. The latter case is why I also assiduously retag [kali-linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kali-linux) questions...

In terms of addressing the problem, perceived or otherwise, I suspect that the type of questions that arouse the ire of the chat denizens, and justifiably so in the majority of these cases, are not asked by people inclined to read tag tips, the help centre or anything else that is going to convince them to think *a little* harder before pasting their questions into the text field.

For that reason, short of adopting a more decriptive tag (eg., [rubbish](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubbish)) for everyone to ignore, simple editing triage seems the most effective approach.

Comment: Please have a care with the Kali tag. I share your pain but it shouldn't become a "bad question tag" (despite the earnest efforts on the part of many askers), try to use it only when the question is specific to Kali.

Comment: @terdon I'll do my best, but the force is strong with the l337...